# Why is some_statement;;;; valid in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++

I am learning C++ and accidentally wrote

```
string s = "Some String";;;;
```

No matter how many semi-colons are there, the compiler won't complain.
This works on almost every statement except inside the if block where the compiler says

```
 ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
```

I am using GCC 4.7

Comment: Why *shouldn't* it work?! `;` is just an empty statement.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a syntax error?

Comment: If that surprises you try statements of numbers: `5;`. They're valid too, apparently.

Comment: Think about it as `string s = "Some String"; NOP; NOP; NOP;` and you'll have your answer to both questions (`NOP` being "no operation").

Comment: @yesboy: When one's are asking such questions, one is absolutely required to explain why one expected it to be invalid. Why did you expect the compiler to complain? What made you think it should be a syntax error? Without it, your question makes no sense whatsoever. It is like asking why `2 + 2` is `4`. How do you expect people to answer this?

Comment: @AndreyT it's not at all unreasonable for a beginner to think that multiple semi-colons are an error but not be able to explain why. Insisting on an explanation means not asking the question.

Comment: @AndreyT I thought that if ; means statement terminator/separator, then my program must have a statement so that I can use this to terminate/separate it.

Comment: @Pete Becker: Well I believe that there is always a rationale behind this way of thinking, even for a beginner. And it is usually something more elaborate than just "it looks weird to me". It makes sense for the person asking the question to explain that rationale, so that we can address it directly, instead of trying to "carpet bomb" the whole issue hoping to hit the proper spot.

Comment: It should be noted that it's not unusual to use `;;;;;;` in code to flag line for later inspection, similar to `\\????`, et al.  If you see it in "foreign" code it likely means the code in that area could use further investigation.

Comment: It should also be noted that empty statements have a real use, in `for` statements, at least.  It's not unusual to see one of the 3 `for` header statements empty.

Comment: @Hot Licks: That's actually not a good example. The syntax of `for` is described by dedicated branches of grammar, designed specifically for `for`, not by a general statement grammar. Only the very first segment of `for` header is actually a "statement" (the second and the third segments are not), and even that first one is a special `for-init-statement`, not a general statement. In other words, the `;`s in `for` header are  hardcoded elements of `for` syntax, completely dissimilar to the `;`s in this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following is a part of the [C++ grammar](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/):

> `expression`<sub>`opt`</sub> `;`

where the subscript `opt` indicates that `expression` is optional.

On the other hand, the grammar for the `if` statement is:

> `if` `(` `condition` `)` `statement`

and `expression`<sub>`opt`</sub> `;` is not a valid `condition`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was not aware of c++ grammar.

Comment: @yesboy Consider reading appendix A of C++ standard draft: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf.

Comment: That is actually wrong. The page you link to defines an expression-statement as `expression_opt ;`. If it was using a Kleene star, it'd allow the following: `1 2 3;` to be a valid statement. What is used as indication of optional parts when talking about grammars is the question mark `?`. Did you mean `expression? ;`?

Comment: I meant to say *in my statement, the asterisk means optional*. The link to the grammar contains the actual, proper grammar definition.

Comment: You probably should replace `*` with `?` as `*` usually means 0 or more, where `?` means zero or one.

Comment: @Slava You are right. Will do.

Comment: @JerryCoffin done --- it looks very good. Thanks for the formatting snippet.

Comment: I think you explanation about `expression?;` is not valid condition not quite correct in this case. if() expects only one statement before else, so `if(..); else return;` is correct but `if(...);;else return;` is not.

Comment: @Slava: Exactly. The second part of the question wasn't about the `condition` part of an `if` statement, it was about `statement1` in `if ( condition ) statement1 else statement2`.

Answer (score 6):

The C++ grammar (like C before it) allows null statements. In some cases they're actually even useful. One case is a loop that puts all the actions into the condition, so the body of the loop doesn't need to do anything. A classic example of this is an implementation of the C `strcpy` function:

```
while (*d++ = *s++)
    ;
```

When you're doing this, you typically do want to put the semicolon on a line by itself like this, not on the end of the same line, like `while (*d++ = *s++);`. The compiler doesn't care about the difference, but putting it on a separate line helps reassure the reader that loop controlling only a single null statement is intentional. Some people prefer to add a comment as well, like:

```
while (*d++ = *s++)
   /* intentional null statement */ ;
```

Personally, I think a semicolon on a line by itself is sufficient, but such is life.

Comment: Just want to note some coding conventions (like Google Style Guide) recommend using empty brackets (`while (*d++ = *s++) {}`) or continue statement (`while (*d++ = *s++) continue;`) instead of null statements.

Comment: Fair enough.  Comment removed.

Answer (score 6):

To add something that has not been mentioned in other answers:

What this sequence of `;;;` stands for will in general case depend on the context in which it is used.

If you declare

```
string s = "Some String";;;;
```

in a *local* scope (i.e. inside a function), then what you have above is a *declaration statement* for variable `s` and the excessive `;`s will stand for empty *statements*, as it has been stated in other answers already. This has always been legal in C++.

But if you do

```
string s = "Some String";;;;
```

in *namespace* scope, then the excessive `;`s no longer stand for empty *statements*. Statements are not allowed in namespace scope. What you have above is a *declaration* (not *declaration statement*, but a mere *declaration*) for variable `s`, followed by a sequence of *empty declarations*. Empty declarations used to be illegal in C++ language before C++11, meaning that in C++98 and in C++03 the above declaration would indeed produce a syntax error if used in namespace scope.

If the above declaration is used in *class* scope, then it is immediately illegal in C++98 and C++03 for other reasons: it includes an initializer, which is not allowed in pre-C++11 versions of language. In C++11 including an initializer in a class scope declaration became legal. In that case the sequence of `;;;` is also a sequence of *empty declarations*, not a sequence of *empty statements*.